# Visual Studio - naming forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

this might be a very very basic question, but what is the best way to name my forms?
I mean, can I use spaces or will that give me problems later on?

**Example**
Should I use "Logged on Popup" or "Logged_on_Popup"?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "name"? The title of the form or the class name?

Comment: The class name and the name that is displayed in the solution explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use spaces. Or Underscores. Microsoft do have some [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) that they recommend. Whilst they don't specifically have any recommendations re: form naming, they may be quite a good read:

> Do favor readability over brevity. The property name CanScrollHorizontally is better than ScrollableX (an obscure reference to the X-axis).
>
> Do not use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.

---

Also, bear in mind that the name used in your code isn't exposed to the end users - whereas the captions of your forms are - make sure that those captions are well chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Since Forms are also classes, you should follow the [Class Namings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xhs4564%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

- Use a noun or noun phrase to name a class.
- Use Pascal case.
- Use abbreviations sparingly.
- Do not use a type prefix, such as C for class, on a class name. For example, use the class name FileStream rather than CFileStream.
- Do not use the underscore character (_).
- Occasionally, it is necessary to provide a class name that begins with the letter I, even though the class is not an interface. This is appropriate as long as I is the first letter of an entire word that is a part of the class name. For example, the class name IdentityStore is appropriate.
- Where appropriate, use a compound word to name a derived class. The second part of the derived class's name should be the name of the base class. For example, `ApplicationException` is an appropriate name for a class derived from a class named `Exception`, because `ApplicationException` is a kind of Exception. Use reasonable judgment in applying this rule. For example, Button is an appropriate name for a class derived from Control. Although a button is a kind of control, making Control a part of the class name would lengthen the name unnecessarily.

So `Log On Popup` is invalid and `Log_On_Popup` should be valid from a compiler perspective, but not from the class naming guidelines. I should opt for `LogOnPopup`. Where some people like to add a suffix to it `LogOnPopupForm`.

Comment: Thanks! I won't use spaces and underscores then :).

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class LoggedOnPopupForm
```

In component name you can use spaces but I don't recommend doing it

Answer (score 0):

Simple,
You can use log_on_popup
If your doubt is how to name it then,  When your Form designer is open, open the **properties window** (If properties window is not there, just right click on the form and select properties), In properties , You will find **(Name)** just type there **log_on_popup** :)